# Simple question about derivatives of integrals

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

Assume that $f$ is differentiable in $\mathbb{R}$ and $f'$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R}$.

Set $F(x)= \int_0^1f(x-t)\,dt$.

Prove that $F'(x) = \int_0^1f'(x-t)\,dt.$

This is the question. 
I thought this is just about the basic theorem about the derivatives of integrals, and according to the theorem, isn't the condition given ($f$ and $f'$ being continuous in $\mathbb{R}$) sufficient enough to prove the following equation?
Or is there more sophisticated method to prove this equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to use the the rule for differentiating under the integral sign (there's an entire wikipedia article about this); if  $f$ and $f'$ are continuous, then the hypotheses of that theorem are certainly satisfied, and the proof will be a one-liner.

A more elementary, but necessarily longer, solution would be to change variables, for example, let $t = x-\alpha$. Then,
\begin{align}
F(x) &= \int_0^1 f(t) \, dt = \int_x^{x-1} f(\alpha) (- \, d\alpha) = \int_{x-1}^x f(\alpha) \, d \alpha.
\end{align}
Now, you can directly apply the standard fundamental theorem of calculus, to calculate the derivative, and then once again use the FTC to re-express that answer back as an integral involving $f'$.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the hypothesis you have are exactly the ones necessary to interchange the integral with the derivative. Hence, you can write $$
F'(x)=\dfrac{d}{dx}\int_0^1f(x-t)dt=\int_0^1\dfrac{d}{dx}f(x-t)dt=\int_0^1f'(x-t)dt=-f(x-1)+f(x),
$$
where in the second equality we have used the fact that $f$ is continuously differentiable in the whole space $\mathbb{R}$ and the fact that you are integrating in the compact set $[0,1]$ (so that you can interchange derivative and integral without problem).